# При переводе числа int во float и обратно теряется точность числа

Tags: java, float, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Вопрос на злобу дня освежить знания о числе с плавающей точкой и потренировать перевод этого числа в двоичную систему и обратно.

[В документах оракла](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) в пункте 5.1.2 приводится пример с потерей данных числа при переводе его в тип `float`, а затем обратно в `int`.

```
class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int big = 1234567890;
        float approx = big;
        System.out.println(big - (int)approx); //output -46
    }
}
```

**Вопрос - почему именно -46?**

Я вручную перевёл число `1234567890` в двоичный вид числа с плавающей точкой. Получилось следующее:
1-ый бит на хранение знака (`0`), следующие `8` битов на хранение экспоненты, оставшиеся `23` бита на хранение мантиссы. Приступим:

Число `1234567890` в двоичной системе будет `1001001100101100000001011010010`. Далее необходимо записать это число в экспонентной форме (т.е. перенести запятую на столько разрядов, чтобы перед ней была только 1 единица). Делаем:
`1,001001100101100000001011010010`

Мы перенесли запятую `30` раз влево, соответственно наша экспонента будет `30 (+127) = 157`.

`157` в двоичной системе будет `10011101`.

Соответственно наше число в экспонентной форме записи примет такой вид:

Знак / экспонента / мантисса

`0 / 10011101 / 00100110010110000000101`

Про знак и экспоненту всё понятно, а вот с мантиссой поступают так: отбрасывают первую единицу и пишут оставшиеся 23 числа (т.к. свободно всего `23` бита). Оставшиеся биты, а именно `1010010` просто отбрасываются.

Соответственно при переводе этого числа обратно в десятичную систему нам как раз и не будет хватать этих `7` бит (`1010010`).

Т.е. наше число примет следующий вид в двоичной системе:

`100100110010110000000101 (0000000)` - добиваем оставшиеся "потерянные 7 битов" нулями.

Данное число представляет собой в десятичной системе `1234567808` (что на **82** меньше исходного).

**Так почему же на выходе в консоли при вычитании чисел мы получаем разницу 46?**

Comment: Эти преобразования используют round-to-nearest mode, т.е. выбирается ближайшее число, которое представимо в нужном формате. В Вашем случае один кандидат меньше исходного числа на 82, другой больше на 46. Выбирается второй, т.к. он "ближе"